# how to fix "[WinError 10038]" of my python3 socket server script with multithread on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multithreading, sockets

Hello I wanted to make a server socket where we can have several clients on the same port.

When I run it on linux (debian and android) the server script works but on windows it doesn't work.

I use Python 3.7.3 but this error is yet in 3.9.0

Server

```
import socket
import threading

from sys import exit as bye

host, port = '', 8000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

def work(s):
    (client, (host, port)) = s.accept()
    print("[+] Connexion :{}:{}".format(host, port))
    t=client.recv(1024)
    client.send(b"Hi "+t)
    client.close()
    s.close()
    bye()

x=[]
for i in range(1000):
    x.append(threading.Thread(target=work, args=(s,)))
    x[i].start()
```

Client

```
import socket

for i in range(1000):
    host, port = '127.0.0.1', 8000
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.send('x'.encode())
    print(s.recv(1024).decode())
```

error is only on windows

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Loutre\Desktop\t.py", line 9, in work
    (client, (host, port)) = s.accept()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 212, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing `s` in `work` even though it's shared among all jobs. I'd expect a different error than that, but I can find C# posts where that error was caused by trying to use a closed socket.

Remove the call to `s.close()` in `work`, and move it to after the threads are joined. Or, better yet, use a `with` block to manage closing for you.